# In a G sheet having cells with data as sparklines is not showing sparklines when sent email through app script in html format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sparklines

I am having a G sheet with cells having data in sparklines and i want to email the same as sparklines through app script in html. But when i sent email blank cells are dispalyed in email in place of sparklines.
Could you please suggest any html code that i have to add in my script to display sparklines!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPARKLINE in the Google Sheet is not displaying in the Email using App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133870/sparkline-in-the-google-sheet-is-not-displaying-in-the-email-using-app-script)

Answer (score -1):

I had faced same issue and I posted the question on stack overflow and got the answer which worked for me. Check below answer:

[SPARKLINE in the Google Sheet is not displaying in the Email using App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133870/sparkline-in-the-google-sheet-is-not-displaying-in-the-email-using-app-script/50146374#50146374)